# How to press a button and click on checkbox

Tags: python-2.6, mechanize-python

How can i click on button and check the check box with mechanize python...
HTML code:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_t" style="width:120px;float:left;margin:10px;margin-top:2px;" value="Apply" disabled="">
```

i tried with:

```
br.click(id ="btn_t")
```

But this throws an error:

```
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching kind 'clickable', id '
btn_t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not a standard submit button, so it probably triggers some `javascript`, which you will have to emulate. If this 'click' triggers a submit, you can try:

```
br.submit()
```